# Can You Post To Facebook Groups? Conflicting Documentation

Tags: facebook

So I am trying to post a video to a group that I created, thus I am the admin, and I get getting the error

`Auth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) No permission to publish the video"`

I have the following permissiosn enabled:

```
'publish_video', 'user_videos', 'publish_to_groups',  'pages_show_list', 'pages_read_engagement', 'pages_manage_posts', 'groups_access_member_info'
```

Now I noticed the docs say:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing/

> Publishing on Groups The app user must be an Admin of the Group you
> are targeting. You will need the app user's User Access Token and they
> must grant your app the publish_to_groups permission.

But the docs over here say:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v18.0/group

> Creating This operation is not supported.

So can I post a video to a group or can I not?